# REST API Teamcity - Get list of builds NOT containing a specific tag?

Tags: rest, teamcity

I want to get a list of all builds which have tag:cal_diff_sel but do not have tag:cal_diff_unres.

I can easily list builds with both:

```
http://<server>/guestAuth/app/rest/builds?locator=tag:cal_diff_sel,tag:cal_diff_unres
```

but putting `~` or `!` within or before tag:cal_diff_unres does nothing useful.

Obviously for a simple count I can query for each and then subtract, but if I want the actual builds, I need to run both queries to exhaustion (nextHref) and then subtract the lists, which seems rather wasteful.

I found nothing in the official docs.

Answer (score 0):

Damnit, why do I always find the answer moments after posting? I swear I tried this before and it didn't work.

```
http://<server>/guestAuth/app/rest/builds?locator=defaultFilter:false,tag:cal_diff_sel,not:tag:cal_diff_unres
```

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that `not:tag:cal_diff_unres` is the current syntax to achieve this. The legacy syntax should work too: `not:tags:(cal_diff_unres)`. Docs [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/2020.1/rest-api-reference.html#Build+Locator).

I wanted to add to that, though--unfortunately, you can't use more than one "not" tag clause (either in the legacy syntax or the current).

If you try to use more than one "not" tag clause in the legacy syntax, you just get a bad result--i.e. a build or builds that only exclude one of the excluded tags. If you use the current syntax, you get a 400 bad request with the following exception: "Only single 'not' dimension is supported in locator."

Comment: Gah! So annoying! Thanks for the warning. Too bad `not:` isn't mentioned anywhere in their document, or they might have mentioned this themselves!

Comment: Haha, yes--it's a surprising omission from the docs for sure :).

Comment: I put in a pull request - still pending at the time of writing: https://github.com/JetBrains/teamcity-documentation/pulls